# How to enable stemming for Indic languages in an ElasticSearch Index?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to configure stemmer using [language analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html) for Indian languages in an ElasticSearch Index?

Answer (score 1):

For languages that support [Dictionary-based stemming using `HunSpell`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-hunspell-tokenfilter.html):

---

### Dictionaries

| Language | Code | Download URL | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kannada | kn_IN | https://github.com/mgharish/kn-hunspell/tree/master/dictionaries | `ಹುಡುಗಿಯರು`→`ಹುಡುಗಿ` |
| Marathi | mr_IN | https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/marathi-spellchecker | `अंतर्ज्ञाना`→`अंतर्ज्ञान` |
| Nepali | ne_NP | https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries/tree/main/dictionaries/ne | `केटाहरू`→`केटा` |
| Sinhala | si_LK | https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries/tree/master/si_LK | `බල්ලන්`→`බල්ල` |
| Tamil | ta_IN | https://github.com/AshokR/TamilNLP/tree/master/tamilnlp/Resources | `பெண்களே`→`பெண்` |

**Files required:**

- `.aff` file: Contains affix rules
- `.dic` files: Contain list of words with applicable rules

**How to install the dictionaries:**

- Download and place those files in a folder with name as the language code, inside `config/hunspell/` folder of ElasticSearch installation.
- Example folder for Tamil: `/etc/elasticsearch/config/hunspell/ta_IN/`

  - Installation path can vary.

---

### Example

#### Create an index

```
PUT /tamil_example
{
   "settings": {
      "index": {
         "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
               "default": {
                  "tokenizer": "standard",
                  "filter":[
                     "lowercase",
                     "decimal_digit",
                     "indic_normalization",
                     "tamil_stemmer"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "filter": {
               "tamil_stemmer": {
                  "type": "hunspell",
                  "locale": "ta_IN"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

#### Test Stemming

```
POST /tamil_example/_analyze
{
    "text": "பெண்கள் நம்பாதே"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{'tokens': [{'end_offset': 7,
   'position': 0,
   'start_offset': 0,
   'token': 'பெண்',
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>'},
  {'end_offset': 15,
   'position': 1,
   'start_offset': 8,
   'token': 'நம்பு',
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>'}]}
```

---

**Notes for missing languages:**

HunSpell Dictionary Collections:

- [Elastic's Collection](https://github.com/elastic/hunspell/blob/master/conf.yaml) ([Downloaded copies](https://github.com/elastic/hunspell/tree/master/dicts))
- [LibreOffice Dictionaries](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries)
- [Firefox Dictionaries](https://mozilla-l10n.github.io/firefox-dictionaries/complete.html)

**General Notes:**

- Quality of stemming will depend on quality of dictionary.

  - Most of the above open-source dictionaries are of below-average quality.
- If you have a very large word list for language, you can consider trying [creating a HunSpell dictionary](https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/issues/10) yourself automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For languages that support Algorthmic stemming using [`stemmer` token-filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html):

---

## Hindi

#### Create an index

```
PUT hindi_example
{
   "settings": {
      "index": {
         "analysis":{
            "analyzer": {
               "default": {
                  "tokenizer": "standard",
                  "filter": [
                     "lowercase",
                     "decimal_digit",
                     "indic_normalization",
                     "hindi_normalization",
                     "hindi_stemmer"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "filter": {
               "hindi_stemmer": {
                  "type": "stemmer",
                  "language": "hindi"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

([Check docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#hindi-analyzer) for more details)

#### Test Stemming

```
POST /hindi_example/_analyze
{
    "text": "लडकियाँ लडकियों"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{'tokens': [{'end_offset': 7,
   'position': 0,
   'start_offset': 0,
   'token': 'लडक',
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>'},
  {'end_offset': 15,
   'position': 1,
   'start_offset': 8,
   'token': 'लडक',
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>'}]}
```

---

## Bengali

#### Create an index

```
PUT bengali_example
{
   "settings": {
      "index": {
         "analysis":{
            "analyzer": {
               "default": {
                  "tokenizer": "standard",
                  "filter": [
                     "lowercase",
                     "decimal_digit",
                     "indic_normalization",
                     "bengali_normalization",
                     "bengali_stemmer"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "filter": {
               "bengali_stemmer": {
                  "type": "stemmer",
                  "language": "bengali"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

([Check docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#bengali-analyzer) for more details)

#### Test Stemming

```
POST /bengali_example/_analyze
{
    "text": "আমাদের জুতাগুলো"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{'tokens': [{'end_offset': 6,
   'position': 0,
   'start_offset': 0,
   'token': 'আমা',
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>'},
  {'end_offset': 15,
   'position': 1,
   'start_offset': 7,
   'token': 'জুতা',
   'type': '<ALPHANUM>'}]}
```